# Do I need to have a CI folder for every project I build?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm fairly new to CodeIgniter and one thing I really can't really understand yet is, do I need to copy the directory tree for codeigniter in every single project I have to create?
I mean imagine I have a folder called "company1" and inside that folder I have several other projects each used for different projects for "company1", kind of like this:

- `Company1`

  - `project1`
  - `project2`
  - ...
  - `projectN`

Do I have to extract codeigniter to every single project folder? By extracting I mean to have the "application" and "system" folders in each project. Another question, I can see that CI has several functions to get data from a database like `get_where`, `select`, `get_max()`, etc. But in order to use these functions you have to have a default database configured in `/application/config/database.php` file, is there another way where I can leave `$db['default']['database'`] equal to `''` so I can select from which database I want to retrieve data from?

I'm sorry if all of this doesn't make sense or if the questions are just plain stupid, as I said before I'm new to CI but I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Does http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/managing_apps.html http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html help at all?

Comment: @stormdrain Thank you those are actually very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Of course, you need to copy /application folder, because there are your application. It may be different for every new projects.
2. You can use the same /system folder (as far as I understand, you can redeclare system folder's path. It would be good for core updating, but also can be bad in such situation: core updates to totally new version (I mean 3 or 2.5, smth from feature) and some of functions/classes became deprecated... You will need to reorganize all of that and it may be not simple. But it's just my fantasy... Okay, as for me, it's not good way to use common /system folder. But I have seen topics about such architect.
3. As I said, you need to have it's own "application" folder for every new project, so no need to make some fixes for config. One project => one application folder => one config => one huge profit! ;)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You really don't have to create multiple applications and system folders. You can have a single applications folder with multiple subdirectories for each of your projects and a common systems folder.

It's explained here. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/managing_apps.html

Since each of your project has different config, it's really not necessary to switch databases. However, if you need multiple databases in a single project, I can suggest [this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html).

As Danny mentioned, it's not a good idea to have them in common folder as updating CI for a single project would be a headache.